# OpenOffice : привязать формулу к столбцу

Tags: excel, open-office

Допустим есть формула, **=SUM(D1:D38)** которая суммирует цены, но если к примеру я укажу цену в столбце **D39** тогда сумма учитываться не будет. Как сделать так, чтобы не проставлять диапазон, а он как-то работал автоматически при расширении цен вниз ?

Comment: `=SUM(D:D)`. Если же надо не от верхней ячейки, а, скажем, от D5, то `=SUM(D:D)-SUM(D1:D4)`. В ОО можно также проверить работоспособность `=SUM(D5:D)` - в MS Excel такое работает в коде, но не на листе.

Comment: К сожелению не один из вариантов не работает. Единсвенное что приходит в голову это поставить -SUM(D1:D1000), но это так, думал есть более оптимальное решение (автоматизированное)

Comment: *не один из вариантов не работает* Что-то Вы не так делаете... попробуйте формулу не руками вводить, а через мастера, а диапазон задавать выбором столбца мышкой...

Comment: Вводил по разному, не определает D, если указывают номер, работает

Answer (score 0):

Суммировать по целому столбцу затратно для вычислений - просчитывается весь диапазон. Для одной формулы это не имеет значения, но если много? Задать диапазон суммирования больше максимально возможного:

```
=СУММ(D1:D5000)
```

*СУММЕСЛИ* умеет сама определять диапазон суммирования:

```
=СУММЕСЛИ(D:D;"<>")
=СУММЕСЛИ(D:D;">0")
```

Как вариант - считать значения в диапазоне:

```
 =СУММ(D1:ИНДЕКС(D:D;СЧЁТ(D1:D5000)))
```

Но будет ошибка, если в диапазоне суммирования будут нечисловые значения или пустые ячейки. Для этого случая:

```
=СУММ(D1:ИНДЕКС(D:D;ПРОСМОТР(9E+307;D1:D5000;СТРОКА(D1:D5000))))
```

где *9E+ 307* - наибольшее число в *Excel*

*Примечание: показанные формулы работают в Excel, как поведут себя в Open-Office Calc - нужно проверять. Возможно, в диапазонах везде нужно указывать строку. Если это так, то самый простой и правильный вариант - СУММ с заведомо б**О**льшим диапазоном.*

Comment: Понял, попробую, вопрос, как можно найти текст и получить его номер ? К примеру где то в ячейке A с неизвестным номером ячейки есть слово HELLO, как найти номер ячейки по слову HELLO ?

Comment: Вопрос не связан с текущим. *ПОИСКПОЗ*